# "boot error" Message When Booting From USB in Laptop

Tags: linux, laptop, boot, linux-mint

Trying to boot Linux Mint 12 in laptop from USB. When I prioritize BIOS to boot from USB, I'm getting a "boot error" message [no other messages]. I press any key and Windows 7 starts booting.

The odd thing is that I have no trouble booting in my desktop (2008 model / Windows XP). I've also tried booting in two different laptops. Both laptops have new hardware [one is a 2010 Dell Inspiron model and another a 2011 Asus U46E model]. So I'm guessing it's a Laptop BIOS issue.

I've tried both Universal-USB-Installer and UNebootin.

I've Googled this extensively and answers don't make any sense to me.

USB format is FAT32. I've also allowed Windows Firewall settings for Universal-USB-Installer [some post suggested that].

Note: ["Boot Error" message when booting Ubuntu 9.10 from USB sticks (Occurs only on 1 PC)](https://superuser.com/questions/133720/boot-error-message-when-booting-ubuntu-9-10-from-usb-sticks-occurs-only-on-1) suggests that it's a USB corruption. But I'm not finding that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Universal-USB-Installer and when the boot option came I did "force boot" on the USB in my BIOS options. Previously, I was just setting USB as the first device to boot.