# Error when I boot a server from a USB key

Tags: linux, centos, usb-flash-drive

I am trying to boot my Linux server using a USB key with CentOS 6.5 installed. It gives me the boot error message

> remove disks or other media, press any key to restart.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Have you changed the boot order?

Comment: Related question.   http://superuser.com/questions/378330/boot-error-message-when-booting-from-usb-in-laptop?rq=1

Comment: Yes i have changed the boot order and it still gives me the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the usb drive being higher in the boot order than the boot device with CentOS installed on it. Most of the time you can just press any key and it will continue on to the next boot device (even though it says it will restart). In bios you may have to change the boot order or disable usb boot overide or a similar setting, it is very bios dependent.

Comment: But he sounded like the usb drive is exactly what he wants to boot to...

Comment: Yes i want to boot to the usb drive. So i still need an asnwer to this problem

Comment: Ok then the server is not able to boot from the usb, how did you create the bootable usb?